# jquery mobile list divider formatting

Tags: jquery, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to change the style of a list divider in a jquery mobile listview, but no luck so far.
The problem is that I'm using an url inside a list divider, and jquery makes it blue and underlined. I want it to be the same as when it isn't a url.

This is what I added to my css to override the jquery css:

```
   a.ui-li-divider{
      text-decoration:  none;
   }
```

But it doesn't do anything. Any ideas?

--
Thanks
Bart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/kpqa5/

```
.ui-li-divider a {
    text-decoration:  none;
    color: black !important;
}
```

## Final notes

If you want to find more about how to customize jQuery Mobile page and widgets then take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)**. It comes with a lot of working examples, including why is !important necessary for jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Yes this works, but what's strange is that color=black; doesn't work in this context?

Answer (score 2):

I know inline style is a bad practice but inline style is working.

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="container">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d">
            <li data-role="list-divider"><a href="#" STYLE="text-decoration:none; color:black;">Mail</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Inbox</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Outbox</a>

            </li>
            <li data-role="list-divider"><a href="#" STYLE="text-decoration:none; color:black;">Contacts</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Friends</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check out the live fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/LB8ZN/

Comment: Yes it is bad style, but yes it works. Good as a temporary solution.

Comment: If @Gajotres see this, he might be able to give good solution.